# Areas where my GitHub Repository has most changes

Tags: git, github

I would like to know the areas within a given GitHub repository that holds the most changes.

The expected result would be:
Object/Class XYZ has 100 commits
Object/Class XPTO has 85 commits.
And so on.

Reason:
I would like to gather this data in order to create Code refactoring tasks where we can improve areas of the code that clearly requires too much maintenance.

It can can be an application a tool where connects directly with GitHub, etc.

Comment: Just to be clear... what are you measuring? Number of commits, number of lines changed, number of characters changed? This is going to be extremely difficult to measure in any meaningful way. Also, I would dispute that a file with a lot of changes means that there's something wrong with the file... maybe there is, maybe there isn't... but I don't think there's going to be much correlation between "activity" and "needs refactoring".

Comment: I would say number of commits and number of lines changed.

Comment: Exactly, there are tons of "maybe" involved. But I will analyse them individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a list of every file modification, you can use:

```
git log --numstat --format=
```

This produces an output like:

```
5       0       README.rst
127     4       README.rst
16      2       setup.py
1       0       test_project/setup.py
6       0       test_project/test_project/tests.py
0       68      README.rst
```

The first column is the number of lines added, the 2nd, lines removed, and the filename. You should be able to sum up the totals for each file and find out which ones change the most.
You can also either track deleted files by working out which ones have a sum of 0 lines, or merge the data with the results of:

```
git log --name-status --format=
```

Which wil list the files and the 'action' that occurred for each commit (Modify, Delete, Rename etc).

Comment: Perfect. With this command, I was able to create a Spreadsheet with all the most updated files across my repo and then I was able to create stories to potentially refactor these stories accordingly. Thank you !